# ¿Como puedo fragmentar grabación en curso de micrófono con reactjs y mediaRecorder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mediaqueries

## Fragmentar grabación de micrófono con reactjs y mediaRecorder

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para grabar audio sobre el micrófono, lo cual estoy usando mediaRecorder sobre ReactJS con un proyecto generado por vite.

Sobre mediaRecorder existe un método llamado [start()](https://runebook.dev/es/docs/dom/mediarecorder/start) el cual se puede pasar como parámetro los milisegundos que pueden pasar hasta hacer un intervalo, mi idea era que en cada intervalo hacer una query a un endpoint para mientras esta la grabación ir recibiendo respuesta constante y no tener que esperar al final para mandar todo.

Pero no logro hacer que lo fragmente, ya que el primer intervalo si manda una grabación como tal, pero a partir de la segundo intervalo ya manda audios vacios.

Mi pregunta es ¿MediaRecorder es capas de hacer lo que requiero, Existen librerías para ello o un método nativo que me ayude?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, dejo código que tengo.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { sendAudioRecording } from '../../services/apiUploadAudio.js'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

interface Recording {
    active: boolean;
    available: boolean;
    url: string;
}
  
interface AudioStream {
    access: boolean;
    recorder: MediaRecorder | null;
    error: string;
    disabled: boolean;
}

interface ChildProps {
    handleSetTextTitle: (text: string) => void;
    handleSetTextAudio: (text: string) => void;
    handleSetColorTitle: (color: string) => void;
    handleSetStyleBorderCard: (color: string) => void;
    handleSetIsLoading: (state: boolean) => void;
    handleSetIsDisabledButtons: (state: boolean) => void;
    isDisabledButtons: boolean
}

const ButtonRecording: React.FC<ChildProps> = ({
    handleSetTextTitle, 
    handleSetTextAudio, 
    handleSetColorTitle, 
    handleSetIsLoading,
    handleSetStyleBorderCard,
    handleSetIsDisabledButtons,
    isDisabledButtons
}) => {
    const [audioStream, setAudioStream]  = useState<AudioStream>({
        access: false,
        recorder: null,
        error: "",
        disabled: false
    });
    
    const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState<Recording>({
        active: false,
        available: false,
        url: ""
    });
    const [textButtonRecording, setTextButtonRecording] = useState("Grabar audio")
    const [styleButtonRecording, setStyleButtonRecording] = useState('primary')

    const chunks = useRef<Blob[]>([]);

    const handleSendAudioRecording = async (record: FormData) => 
        await sendAudioRecording(record)

    const handleClickRecording = () => {
        if(!isRecording.active){
            handleSetIsLoading(true)
            setTextButtonRecording('Parar grabacion ...')
            setStyleButtonRecording('danger')
            handleSetTextTitle("Estas grabando con microfono ...") 
            handleSetColorTitle('text-info') 
            handleSetStyleBorderCard('info')
            return audioStream.recorder?.start(3000)
        }
        if(isRecording.active){
            handleSetIsDisabledButtons(true)
            handleSetTextTitle("Transcribiendo audio a texto...") 
            setTextButtonRecording('transcribiendo grabacion')
            setStyleButtonRecording('primary')
            return audioStream.recorder?.stop()
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleRecording = () => {
            // Verificar si la función getUserMedia está disponible en el navegador
            if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                handleSetTextTitle("Problemas de compatibilidad") 
                handleSetTextAudio('getUserMedia no es compatible con este navegador.') 
                handleSetColorTitle("text-warning.") 
                return false;
            }

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then((mic: MediaStream ) => {
                let mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder | null = null;

                try { mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mic, { mimeType: "audio/webm" }) } 
                catch (err) { console.log(err) }

                const track = mediaRecorder?.stream.getTracks()[0];

                if (track) { track.onended = () => console.log("ended");}

                if (mediaRecorder) {
                    mediaRecorder.onstart = () => {
                        setIsRecording({
                            active: true,
                            available: false,
                            url: ""
                        });
                    };
                
                    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
                        const formAudio = new FormData();
                        formAudio.append('audio', e?.data);
                        handleSendAudioRecording(formAudio).then((response) => {
                            handleSetTextAudio(response.data.response?.transcribe)
                            handleSetTextTitle("Tu audio dice los siguiente: ")
                            setTextButtonRecording("Subir otro audio")
                            setStyleButtonRecording("success")
                            handleSetColorTitle("text-success")
                            handleSetIsDisabledButtons(false)
                        }).finally(()=> handleSetIsLoading(false))
                        chunks.current.push(e.data);
                    };
            
                    mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
                        const url = URL.createObjectURL(chunks.current[0]);
                        chunks.current = [];

                        setIsRecording({
                            active: false,
                            available: true,
                            url
                        });
                    };

                    setAudioStream({
                        ...audioStream,
                        access: true,
                        recorder: mediaRecorder
                    });
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                setTextButtonRecording("Sin permiso de micrófono")
                setStyleButtonRecording('danger')
                setAudioStream({ ...audioStream, error, disabled:true });
            });
        }

        handleRecording()
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])

    return (
        <Button
            variant={styleButtonRecording}
            onClick={handleClickRecording}
            children={textButtonRecording}
            disabled={audioStream.disabled ? true : isDisabledButtons}
        />
    )   
}

export default ButtonRecording;
```